# FCNN: Is there a keras utility which can give me the input region of an image from output pixel coordinates

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, backtrace

Lets say input image is of dimension 128*128 and the final output layer is of dimension 10*10.
I want to know which region of input controls the value on (4,5)th co-ordinate of the output. I'm able to compute it manually. An answer for some network can be a square region of length 20 pixels with (12,15) being the co-ordinate of top left vertex.

**Manual traceback**: We can start tracking the region backwards. For example `MaxPooling2D(2)` layer will double your region. `Conv2D(padding ='same')` output size will shift your region. `Conv2D(padding ='valid')`  will not change your region.

Since this is a deterministic and *easy* problem, there should be a function somewhere which takes in a [keras] model and output co-ordinate and returns back the input region bounding box. 
Thanks !